# Multitple Languages in Cakephp 2.0

Tags: cakephp

i'm having an application with multiple languages in cakephp 2.0. It's in english and in another language. All the contents like menus and respective data are generated from the database. I'm done with english language, but have no idea how to have same content in another language. Should i create two separate database or have other ways of solving this feature in cakephp 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link to Internationalization and Localization for CakePHP 2.0.

This will give you a bit of an idea of how to tackle the issue.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html

Answer (score 0):

I've just started a multi-language site - blogging as I go, the entry relating to language settings is [here](http://markfightscode.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/day-9-of-30-day-startup.html)  I can confirm that the cookbook as mention already is of great help, as is this article [Localizing Japan.](http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2011/11/10/localizing-a-cakephp-application/)

Answer (score 0):

put this code app->config->config.php

array('eng','ger','tha'),'default'=> 'eng');

put appcontrol put this code




    if ($this->_checkLanguage()) {
                $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }
            if ($this->Session->check('Config.language')) {
                Configure::write('Config.language', $this->Session->read('Config.language'));
                // $this->redirect($this->referer());
            }


how to access ctp page

you make three languages 
you go project->app->local-> by default there one folder only eng. but make three languages like ger, thai so you make this folder eng, ger, thai,
inside folder you put this code like 
[image: local]
image no1 for eng.
[image]
img no2.for ger.
[image]
img no 3for thai.
[image]